# upgrading weblogic domain using silent mode keep showing xml errors

Tags: xml, oracle, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

if you are trying to upgrade weblogic using silent mode (using command line) you have to do couple of things.

1-setting the environment using **server/bin/set/setWLSEnv.sh**

2-[create xml file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/xml_ref.htm#CACIDHAJ) and attach it in the upgrade command.
our XML is like this :

```
<plugin-silent-responses>
  <group name="DomainSelectionGroup">
    <plugin name="SelectWebLogicVersionPlugIn">
      <input-adapter name="ChoiceIA">
        <bind-property name="selectedChoiceIds">
          <value>10.3.0.0</value>
        </bind-property>
      </input-adapter>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="DomainDirectorySelectionPlugIn">
      <input-adapter name="IA">
        <bind-property name="selectedFile">
        ...
        ...
        ...
</plugin-silent-responses>
```

3- then navigate to domain location and run the command upgrade:

java weblogic.Upgrade -mode silent -type domain [-responses weblogic-upgrade-domain-responses.xml] [-out file]

but we get ERRORS like :

```
Calling Wizard framework for upgrade: args2: [-mode=silent, -file=wcf/plugin_silent_wizard.xml, -p:plugin:plugin.silent.response.file=weblogic-upgrade-domain-responses.xml, -log=stdout, -p:plugin:plugin.executionPlan.file=weblogic/upgrade/domain/execplan.xml, -p:plugin:I18N_PLUGIN=weblogic/upgrade/i18n_upgrade, -p:plugin:TARGET_VERSION=12.1.1.0]
2013-03-16 10:01:10,055 ERROR [inputAdapter_silent] com.oracle.cie.wizard.WizardController - Uncaught Exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at weblogic.upgrade.domain.directoryselection.SelectWebLogicVersionPlugIn.validateInputAdapter(SelectWebLogicVersionPlugIn.java:50)
        at com.bea.plateng.wizard.plugin.silent.tasks.InputAdapterSilentTask.execute(InputAdapterSilentTask.java:178)
        at com.oracle.cie.wizard.silent.tasks.AbstractSilentTask.run(AbstractSilentTask.java:28)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
A fatal error has occurred.  This application will terminate.
```

or this ERROR:

```
743 ERROR [execute] com.bea.plateng.wizard.plugin.silent.tasks.ExecutePlugInTask - Execute Exception ... weblogic.management.ManagementException: Error during transformation: weblogic/upgrade/domain/directoryselection/SelectWebLogicVersion.xsl
```

it's obvious the error here is in the xml file values

and we followed oracle instuction as here to get it from `(config.xml)` **:**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/xml_ref.htm#CACIDHAJ

and we try all the alternatives like `<value>10.3</value>` and we delete it and ....
but still not working.

also we open a case with oracle support for more than one week without any solution.

I see this error happen to some people because of the SSL configuration  but this is not our case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are upgrading from version newer than wls 9.0 you shouldn't fill your weblogic version as described in oracle DOCs.
so don't get it from `(config.xml)`

the value have to be `<value>9.0 or higher</value>`  you can't guess it easily and it's not in [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/xml_ref.htm#CACIDHAJ).

so your xml will be something like that:

```
<plugin-silent-responses>
  <group name="DomainSelectionGroup">
    <plugin name="SelectWebLogicVersionPlugIn">
      <input-adapter name="ChoiceIA">
        <bind-property name="selectedChoiceIds">
          <value>9.0 or higher</value>
        </bind-property>
      </input-adapter>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="DomainDirectorySelectionPlugIn">
      <input-adapter name="IA">
        <bind-property name="selectedFile">
        ...
        ...
        ...
</plugin-silent-responses>
```